# Помогите решить задачу "Башня"

Tags: python

Башня
Петя в очередной раз купил себе набор из кубиков. На этот раз он выстроил из них настоящую крепость — последовательность из N столбиков, высота каждого столбика составляет Ai кубиков.

Вскоре ему стало интересно, насколько его крепость защищена от жуликов и воров. Для этого он ввел понятие башни. Башней называется любая последовательность из K столбиков подряд (где K — любимое число Пети). Защищенность башни определяется как суммарная высота всех столбиков этой башни (чем она больше, тем громаднее и ужаснее она кажется), умноженная на минимум высоты столбиков башни (т.к. враги, очевидно, будут пытаться проникнуть через самое слабое место башни). Неприступность крепости определяется как сумма защищенностей каждой из башен.

Петя решил как можно скорее посчитать, какова же неприступность его крепости. Однако вскоре он понял, что недостаточно знать высоту каждого из столбиков. В зависимости от того, как сгруппировать столбики в башни, получится разный результат. В различных вариантах группировки часть столбиков могут не принадлежать ни одной из башен. Разумеется, Петя выберет то разбиение на башни, при котором неприступность будет максимальна.

Петя успешно справился со своей задачей, но теперь Правительство Флатландии решило защитить свой горный курорт. Правительство уже построило крепость из кубиков (просто кубики были побольше). Теперь вы должны помочь Правительству посчитать неприступность этой крепости. Единственная трудность состоит в том, что у Правительства было очень много денег, и поэтому крепость была построена очень длинная.

Входные данные

В первой строке содержатся число N — количество столбиков в крепости и число K — любимое число Пети (1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 100 000). Далее в следующей строке содержатся N целых чисел, обозначающих Ai (1 ≤ Ai ≤ 106).

Выходные данные

В первой строке выведите число Q — количество башен в оптимальном разбиении. Далее выведите Q чисел — номера первых столбиков каждой башни.

Примеры
Ввод
Вывод
8 3
1 2 3 4 1 6 7 8
2
2 6
1 1
1
1
1
Ограничения
Время выполнения: 2 секунды
Есть такой код:

```
from collections import deque
 
n, k = map(int, input().split())
x, d, ssum = list(map(int, input().split())), deque(), 0
b = deque()
for i in range(k) :
    b.append(0)
    b.append(deque())
for i in range(n):
    if k == 1:
        res = [int(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
        break
    ssum += x[i]
    if i >= k :
        ssum -= x[i - k]
        if d[0] == i - k :
            d.popleft()
    while len(d) and x[d[-1]] >= x[i]:
        d.pop()
    d.append(i)
    if i >= k - 1:
        bls = b.popleft()
        bli = deque(b.popleft())
        bri = b.pop()
        brs = b[-1]
        b.append(bri)
        if brs > bls + x[d[0]] * ssum :
            b.append(brs)
            b.append(bri)
        else :
            bli.append(i-k+2)
            b.append(bls + x[d[0]] * ssum)
            b.append(bli)
if k != 1 :
    res = b[-1]
print(len(res))
print(*res)
```

Comment: В прошлых темах Вы показывали свои попытки. Не изменяйте этой традиции.

Comment: ОК. Приведённый код работает?

Comment: Да, но превышает время работы

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте инициализировать b как массив, а не дек. В коде вы обращаетесь к элементу b квадратными скобками, что происходит на много медленнее, чем обращение к элементу массива.

Comment: Нет, не проходит

Comment: Нуу, я тогда не знаю. Попробуйте заранее посчитать префиксную сумму всех кубиков.

Comment: И скиньте код, который вы сделали с массивом pls?

Comment: Получилось?))))

Comment: что-то никак(((

Comment: А вы решили задачу Небоскрёбы или Сообщающиеся сосуды? Если несложно, поделитесь кодом пожалуйста. Или кодом решения задачи Башня :)