# Python неправильный формат вывода

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Есть код, который решает задачу по программированию. В тестирующей системе пишет, что не прошло всего 2 теста из 50. В обоих тестах написано неправильный формат вывода. Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

Задача:

Петя в очередной раз купил себе набор из кубиков. На этот раз он выстроил из них настоящую крепость — последовательность из N столбиков, высота каждого столбика составляет Ai

кубиков.

Вскоре ему стало интересно, насколько его крепость защищена от жуликов и воров. Для этого он ввел понятие башни. Башней называется любая последовательность из K
столбиков подряд (где K

— любимое число Пети). Защищенность башни определяется как суммарная высота всех столбиков этой башни (чем она больше, тем громаднее и ужаснее она кажется), умноженная на минимум высоты столбиков башни (т.к. враги, очевидно, будут пытаться проникнуть через самое слабое место башни). Неприступность крепости определяется как сумма защищенностей каждой из башен.

Петя решил как можно скорее посчитать, какова же неприступность его крепости. Однако вскоре он понял, что недостаточно знать высоту каждого из столбиков. В зависимости от того, как сгруппировать столбики в башни, получится разный результат. В различных вариантах группировки часть столбиков могут не принадлежать ни одной из башен. Разумеется, Петя выберет то разбиение на башни, при котором неприступность будет максимальна.

Петя успешно справился со своей задачей, но теперь Правительство Флатландии решило защитить свой горный курорт. Правительство уже построило крепость из кубиков (просто кубики были побольше). Теперь вы должны помочь Правительству посчитать неприступность этой крепости. Единственная трудность состоит в том, что у Правительства было очень много денег, и поэтому крепость была построена очень длинная.

Входные данные

В первой строке содержатся число N
— количество столбиков в крепости и число K — любимое число Пети (1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 100 000). Далее в следующей строке содержатся N целых чисел, обозначающих Ai (1 ≤ Ai ≤ 106)

.

Выходные данные

В первой строке выведите число Q
— количество башен в оптимальном разбиении. Далее выведите Q чисел — номера первых столбиков каждой башни.

Код:

```
from collections import deque
 
n, k = map(int, input().split())
x, d, ssum = list(map(int, input().split())), deque(), 0
b = [(0,0) for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    ssum += x[i]
    if i >= k :
        ssum -= x[i - k]
        if d[0] == i - k :
            d.popleft()
    while len(d) and x[d[-1]] >= x[i]:
        d.pop()
    d.append(i)
    if i >= k - 1:
        nb = (b[i-k][0] + x[d[0]] * ssum, i-k+2)
        b[i] = max(b[i-1], nb, key=lambda x: x[0])
i = n - 1
d = deque()
j = b[-1][1]
d.appendleft(j)
while i !=0:
    i -= 1
    j1 = b[i][1]
    if j-k>=j1 :
        d.appendleft(j1)
        j = j1
print(int(len(d)))
for i in d:
    print(int(i),end = ' ')
```

Еще вариант кода, та же ошибка:

```
from collections import deque
 
n, k = map(int, input().split())
x, d, ssum = list(map(int, input().split())), deque(), 0
b = [(0, 0) for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    ssum += x[i]
    if i >= k:
        ssum -= x[i - k]
        if d[0] == i - k:
            d.popleft()
    while len(d) and x[d[-1]] >= x[i]:
        d.pop()
    d.append(i)
    if i >= k - 1:
        nb = (b[i - k][0] + x[d[0]] * ssum, i - k + 2)
        b[i] = max(b[i - 1], nb, key=lambda x: x[0])
i = n - 1
d = []
j = b[-1][1]
d.append(str(int(j)))
while i != 0:
    i -= 1
    j1 = b[i][1]
    if j - k >= j1:
        d.append(str(int(j1)))
        j = j1
print(int(len(d)))
print(" ".join(reversed(d)))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите решить задачу "Башня"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152157/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%91%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d1%8f)

Comment: Слушайте, ваш Петя с кубиками уже порядком утомил. уже два-три раза он со своей инфантильностью на этом сайте появляется.

Comment: Нет, здесь код другой и проблема другая. Просто задачи одни и те же

Comment: Но здесь же вопрос не в задаче, а в формате вывода у языка Python в данном коде

Comment: а какие тесты не прошел не известно?

Comment: К сожалению нет

Comment: а для чего в конце `print()`

Comment: А, это я просто проверял последний отступ, вдруг в нем беда. Но нет

Comment: Может проблема в том, что Ваш вывод заканчивается на пробел, а надо, что бы заканчивался числом?

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогло

Comment: ну и как тут угадать?)

Comment: Самое интересное, что остальные 48 тестов прошли

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вместо

```py
    for i in d:
       print(int(i),end = ' ')
```

Написать `print(*d)`

Answer (score 1):

При таких вводных данных

```
8 3
3 3 1 3 4 1 3 6
```

вывод

```
3
0 3 6
```

вместо

```
2
3 6
```

Исправил одну строку

```
while i >= k:    
#while i !=0:    
    i -= 1
    j1 = b[i][1]
```

и задача прошла.